# links to anchors not springing to the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MTWu5/

Centered page, with sticky header. Inside the header there's menu links to anchors in the page. My problem is when I click on them, I want the anchor to scroll just under the header, not behind it.

How could I do this??

Comment: None of the answers can be applied on my problem. They either dont work or they apply margins on the anchors that mess up the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i'd write the anchor that way.

```
<a name="anchor" id="anchor"></a>
```

If you don't use the close tag for the a element, no position style can be applied without missed up everything.

Then i just applied that style

```
#anchor{position:absolute;margin-top:-100px;}
```

It seems to works. Your layout is preserved, no margin. That solution works only if you work with fixed height. The margin top is the height of your header.

Hope that is what you were looking for.

Link to example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTWu5/8/)

Answer (score -1):

hai your problem is fixed "The path is: http://jsfiddle.net/MTWu5/2/